# 3 images centered in a row

Tags: html, css, image, inline

I am trying to have three images centered in a row and then centered on the page. I've got them all in a row but I cannot get them centered. Any suggestions on getting my group to the middle? I tried 0 auto on the contain class and on the social class. so close!!

My HTML: first thing is div class=contain to wrap the whole thing, but for some reason if I try to include the class contain in HTML it disppears on Stack Overflow so excuse that.

```css
.contain {
  max-width: 960px;
  text-align: center;
}

.social {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contain">
  <div align="center;" class="social">
    <img src="http://theinvicto.com/wp-
content/uploads/2017/12/facebook.png" alt="" width="75" height="75" />
  </div>
  <div align="center;" class="social">
    <img src="http://theinvicto.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/twitter.png" alt="" width="75" height="75" />
  </div>
  <div align="center;" class="social">
    <img src="http://theinvicto.com/wp-
content/uploads/2017/12/instagram.png" alt="" width="75" height="75" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note: `align` is obsolete. Don't use that. Also, the `<img>` tag does not use or need a closing slash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I would recommend is to make use of **[`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)** container for the elements.

With flexbox, all you need is three different styles in order to centralise elements both horizontally and vertically:

- **[`display: flex;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)**
- **[`align-items: self;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items)**
- **[`justify-content: center;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)**

Note that you'll also need to set a **[`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height)** on the container, so that the elements can actually fill the vertical space.

This can be seen in the following, with a **[`border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border)** added to showcase the area that the `.container` element occupies:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.social {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div align="center;" class="social">
    <img src="http://theinvicto.com/wp-
content/uploads/2017/12/facebook.png" alt="" width="75" height="75" />
  </div>
  <div align="center;" class="social">
    <img src="http://theinvicto.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/twitter.png" alt="" width="75" height="75" />
  </div>
  <div align="center;" class="social">
    <img src="http://theinvicto.com/wp-
content/uploads/2017/12/instagram.png" alt="" width="75" height="75" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: WOO! The other answers were close but ultimately this had everything centered perfectly and did the trick! THANK YOU!

Comment: Well, the answer has been accepted but flexbox just more complicates the already verbose HTML and I would never do it this way. @Emigriff

Answer (score 1):

### html

```
<div class="content">
    <div>
        <img src="facebook.png" alt="" width="75" height="75"/>
    </div>

    <div>
        <img src="twitter.png" alt="" width="75" height="75"/>
    </div>

    <div>
        <img src="instagram.png" alt="" width="75" height="75" />
    </div>
</div>
```

### css

```
.content { 
    text-align:center; 
}
```

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer. Simple and practical and works everywhere since forever.

Comment: I apologise I didn't see this until now!

Comment: @Emigriff I believe you can change that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can edit the css file, remove the `float:left;` :

```css
.contain {
     max-width:960px;
     text-align:center;
  }

 .social {
 position:relative;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<div align="center">
<div align="center;" class="social">
<img src="http://theinvicto.com/wp-
content/uploads/2017/12/facebook.png" alt="" width="75" height="75" />
</div>
<div align="center;" class="social">
<img src="http://theinvicto.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/twitter.png" 
alt="" width="75" height="75" />
</div>
<div align="center;" class="social">
<img src="http://theinvicto.com/wp-
content/uploads/2017/12/instagram.png" alt="" width="75" height="75" />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This helped! and then ultiamtely the flex solution below centered everything well. thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Using `flex` is a great solution, but here's a solution that uses what you already have. By removing `float: left` from your existing code we can get the desired result.

```css
.contain {
  max-width: 960px;
  text-align: center;
}

.social {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contain">
  <div align="center;" class="social">
    <img src="http://theinvicto.com/wp-
content/uploads/2017/12/facebook.png" alt="" width="75" height="75" />
  </div>
  <div align="center;" class="social">
    <img src="http://theinvicto.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/twitter.png" alt="" width="75" height="75" />
  </div>
  <div align="center;" class="social">
    <img src="http://theinvicto.com/wp-
content/uploads/2017/12/instagram.png" alt="" width="75" height="75" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping your current code, simply remove the `flex: left`: ([JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/kwueaxr6/3/)):

```
.contain {
  max-width: 960px;
  text-align: center;
}

.social {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

If based on your [browser compatibility requirements](https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) you can afford to use [`display: flex;` (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) then that's the easiest way ([jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/kwueaxr6/2/)):

```
.contain {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.social {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

There's an excellent flexbox tutorial here: [flexbox froggy](http://flexboxfroggy.com/). Floats are pretty strange and I personally find flexes much more intuitive.