# Keep Newsletter form fixed to the background image?

Tags: html, css

I need to make a website without breaking it's structure. But, I've stepped into a problem. I was suggested to put a Newsletter Form on it, so I did. But when I try to resize the window (to check if it breaks), it's not breaking, but it is decentering, is there a way to make it always centers in relation to it's background?

*Normal Size Centered:*
[image: Normal Size Centered]

*Resized Not Centered:*
[image: Resized Not Centered]

I've tried `vertical-aling:baseline; | position:sticky; | top:16.5%; bottom:16,5%`

*CSS:*

```css
.boletim .caixa_email{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:999;
    margin:0 auto;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:33%;
    text-align:center;
    width:50%;
    font-family:Bebas Neue Regular;
    font-size:1vw;
}

input[type=email], input[type=submit]{
    width:45%;
    height:auto;
    padding: 12px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

*HTML:*

```html
<form action="action_page.php">
    <div class="boletim">
            <img src="Resumo.png" id="newsletter" alt="">

        <div class="caixa_email">
            <h1 id="texto_email">Inscreva-se em nosso boletim para receber ofertas!</h1>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="exemplo@exemplo.com.br">
            <input type="submit" value="Inscrever-se">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I want to make it always centered (in relation to its background) when resizing the window.

Comment: Your best bet would be with flexbox. Can you add the HTML code please? Here's [*a sample*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47645462/3-images-centered-in-a-row/47645505#47645505) showcasing how to vertically center with flexbox, but it's hard to apply this to your code without your HTML as well.

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the post with the HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with `transform`

```
.boletim .caixa_email{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:999;
    margin:0 auto;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    text-align:center;
    width:50%;
    font-family:Bebas Neue Regular;
    font-size:1vw;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Nice, but this can also be achieved with Flex, no need of Position absolute.

Answer (score 0):

This result can be achieved with the simple Flex, no need of absolute position.
Give background to the background class in css or you can put image in there and make img absolute with height: 100%; width: 100%; left:0; top:0;

```css
input[type=email], input[type=submit]{
    width:45%;
    height:auto;
    padding: 12px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.background {
  background: #999;
  height: 100vh;
}
form {
height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">

  <form action="action_page.php">
      <div class="caixa_email">
          <h1 id="texto_email">Inscreva-se em nosso boletim para receber ofertas!</h1>
          <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="exemplo@exemplo.com.br">
          <input type="submit" value="Inscrever-se">
      </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

See the result in full page snippet

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But unfortunaly, this didn't worked as wanted, but thanks again for the support!